# DynamoDB retrieve last row

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

i need some help with DynamoDB.
I have table as following:

```
| Shortener (Hash key) | ShortenedURL (Range key) | LongURL      |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| "My webpage url"     | "1"                       | "example.net"|
| "My webpage url"     | "6"                       | "example.com"|
| "My webpage url"     | "4"                       | "example.eu" |
```

How to retrieve the row with biggest number in "ShortenedURL"?
Im totally new to DynamoDB & NoSQL stuff. Using AWS PHP SDK.
Tried to search for hours and didnt find anything useful. Everything i tried ended with result like "1" or "4".

Comment: This sounds like you need to spend some time on some tutorials. Here's someplace to start: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStartedPHPQuery.html

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting downvoted: it's a well-worded question and a question that I think S.O. is perfect for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you can `Query` with the following arguments:

- hashKey is "My webpage url"
- No condition on the rangeKey
- limit is 1 (you only want one thing)
- withScanIndexForward=false (this goes from biggest to smallest)

This will only work if your rangeKey is a Number type.  If it's a String, then you can only get lexicographical ordering, so "last" may be weird (these three strings appear in this order: `["1, "10", "2", ...]`).

Answer (score 0):

Does your range key have to be String?
If it's a number you can select it to retrieve the biggest one since range key have index which gives them order.

Either way, you can [use the Query API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_query) and set the index backwards by specifying `ScanIndexForward` as `false`.